# How to write loop with using other list items?

Tags: ansible

I'm not familiar with Ansible and struggling writing script.

In the first task, execute the query if the target job is able to terminate. 
In task 2, execute another query to terminate jobs that meet the condition. However, task1 and task 2 is executed sequentially, so I don't have a solution to use the values stored in `job_id_list` and `query_result` in combination.

```
# task1
- name: Check the status of specific jobs
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  shell: psql -t -database -c "select count(*) from table_a a inner join table_b b on b.job_id = a.job_id where b.job_id={{ item }} and b.submitted_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '10 minutes';"
  with_items: {{ job_id_list }}
  register: query_result

# task2
- name: kill job when the result of task1 is 0
  shell: psql -t database -c "update table_b set status='TERMINATED' where job_id={{ XXX }};" # here I struggle...
  with_items: {{ query_result }}
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  when: query_result.stdout|int = 0
```

Comment: Post an example of ``query_result.results`` and ``job_id_list``. See [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `job_id_list` which is a list of items you iterate over in Task#1.
Querying the database you get back `count(*)` which returns number count for that job_id.
In Task#2 you want to iterate over the query result which is a number or a list of numbers(job counts) and you don'd have job_id here. You have to iterate over the same list `job_id_list` but only when the `query_result` is 0 in order to have the `job_id` available. I hope this helps!

Edited: When I reread the query again I think your logic may be wrong.
Instead of getting the count you may get the id return and then in Task#2 to iterate over the list of ids to update.